# Populate a LINQ table in code?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Question: I want to populate a LINQ table from code, not DataBase.

Is it possible ?

```
System.Data.Linq.Table<Question> myquestions = new System.Data.Linq.Table<Question>();
```

Then something like:

```
myquestions.Rows.Add(aquestion);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just populate a regular DataTable and you can use it from LINQ

```
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var dt = new DataTable();
      dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
      dt.Columns.Add("Project Name", typeof(string));
      dt.Columns.Add("Project Date", typeof(DateTime));

      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
        var row = dt.NewRow();
        row.ItemArray = new object[] { i, "Title-" + i.ToString(), DateTime.Now.AddDays(i * -1) };
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
      }

      var pp = from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
               where (int)p["Id"] > 2
               select p;

      foreach (var row in pp)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(row["Id"] + "\t" + row["Project Name"] + "\t" + row["Project Date"]); 
      }

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

In the code above you can see how to use LINQ to filter out certain records from the DataTable. You'll need to add the System.Data.DataSetExtensions assembly to your references

IEnumerables are readonly so you can't really do it the way you're asking, but what I've presented is the correct way.

Comment: Error: System.Data.DataTable contains no definition for AsEnumerable... (.NET 4.0, ASP.NET MVC 3)

Comment: The .AsEnumerable() method is available in another assembly called System.Data.DataSetExtensions, so you'll need to add a reference to that assembly. Normally in new projects (Vs.NET 2010) this assembly is added by default.

Comment: Since he fully qualified his table in the example, me thinks that the OP may not have included the System.Linq namespace?  EDIT: Ninja'd

Comment: PS:  dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int)); // Much slicker

Comment: @Quandary, yes, you're right. I just typed out the code for you, I don't normally use DataTables :)

Comment: Note: It needs: using System.Data; and System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll referenced. Just referencing the assembly won't do the trick, you need to declare using.

Comment: Note: Requires reference and using directive of: Dynamic.dll (not System.Dynamic) [using System.Dynamic.Linq].

Comment: @Quandary, are you using .NET 3.5 or 4.0? In my 4.0 project I do have Syste.Data in my using and I do have System.Data.DataSetExtensions in my references. That's it. I've updated my answer to include the complete source code along with the using statements

Comment: @Shiv Kumar: This is sufficient for AsEnumerable, but Dynamic.dll is required for Rows.AsQueryable().

Comment: @Shiv Kumar: See the C# samples at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb330936.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you misunderstood something. LINQ is a query language with no side-effects. Thus you can't fill up any structure with it. You can only create a query against any existing information and do some kind of transformation or filtering.

Afterwards you can use this query to fill up some element by using `foreach()`, `ToList()` or `ToArray()`, but you cannot directly use LINQ to insert any element into some other object or collection.